Having issues with my implementation of Lexical in my React typescript and tailwinds project
I am implementing a basic rich text editor. I am trying to implement bold, italic, underline and strikethrough. A few issues:

Underline and strikethrough don't show up. Even when I inspect element.
Bold and italic don't work at the same time

ToolbarPlugin.tsx
import { useLexicalComposerContext } from '@lexical/react/LexicalComposerContext';
import { mergeRegister } from '@lexical/utils';
import { INSERT_UNORDERED_LIST_COMMAND, insertList } from '@lexical/list';
import {
    $getSelection,
    $isRangeSelection,
    CAN_REDO_COMMAND,
    CAN_UNDO_COMMAND,
    FORMAT_ELEMENT_COMMAND,
    FORMAT_TEXT_COMMAND,
    REDO_COMMAND,
    SELECTION_CHANGE_COMMAND,
    UNDO_COMMAND,
} from 'lexical';
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { ToolbarButton } from '.';
import {
    faRotateRight,
    faRotateLeft,
    faBold,
    faItalic,
    faUnderline,
    faStrikethrough,
    faAlignLeft,
    faAlignCenter,
    faAlignRight,
    faListDots,
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import {
    $patchStyleText,
    $getSelectionStyleValueForProperty,
} from '@lexical/selection';
import ColorPicker from '../Color/ColorPicker';

const LowPriority = 1;

export const ToolbarPlugin: React.FC = () => {
    const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext();
    const toolbarRef = useRef(null);
    const [canUndo, setCanUndo] = useState(false);
    const [canRedo, setCanRedo] = useState(false);
    const [isBold, setIsBold] = useState(false);
    const [isItalic, setIsItalic] = useState(false);
    const [isUnderline, setIsUnderline] = useState(false);
    const [isStrikethrough, setIsStrikethrough] = useState(false);

    const [fontColor, setFontColor] = useState<string>('#000');

    const applyStyleText = useCallback(
        (styles: Record<string, string>, skipHistoryStack?: boolean) => {
            editor.update(
                () => {
                    const selection = $getSelection();
                    if (selection !== null) {
                        $patchStyleText(selection, styles);
                    }
                },
                skipHistoryStack ? { tag: 'historic' } : {},
            );
        },
        [editor],
    );

    const onFontColorSelect = useCallback(
        (value: string) => {
            applyStyleText({ color: value });
        },
        [applyStyleText],
    );

    const updateToolbar = useCallback(() => {
        const selection = $getSelection();
        if ($isRangeSelection(selection)) {
            // Update text format
            setIsBold(selection.hasFormat('bold'));
            setIsItalic(selection.hasFormat('italic'));
            setIsUnderline(selection.hasFormat('underline'));
            setIsStrikethrough(selection.hasFormat('strikethrough'));
            setFontColor(
                $getSelectionStyleValueForProperty(selection, 'color', '#000'),
            );
        }

    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        return mergeRegister(
            editor.registerUpdateListener(({ editorState }) => {
                editorState.read(() => {
                    updateToolbar();
                });
            }),
            editor.registerCommand(
                SELECTION_CHANGE_COMMAND,
                () => {
                    updateToolbar();
                    return false;
                },
                LowPriority,
            ),
            editor.registerCommand(
                FORMAT_TEXT_COMMAND,
                (format) => {
                    console.log('format', format);
                    const selection = $getSelection();
                    if (!$isRangeSelection(selection)) {
                        console.error('Invalid selection');
                        return false;
                    }
                    selection.formatText(format);
                    updateToolbar();
                    return true;
                },
                LowPriority,
            ),
            editor.registerCommand(
                CAN_UNDO_COMMAND,
                (payload) => {
                    setCanUndo(payload);
                    return false;
                },
                LowPriority,
            ),
            editor.registerCommand(
                CAN_REDO_COMMAND,
                (payload) => {
                    setCanRedo(payload);
                    return false;
                },
                LowPriority,
            ),
            editor.registerCommand(
                INSERT_UNORDERED_LIST_COMMAND,
                () => {
                    insertList(editor, 'bullet');
                    return false;
                },
                LowPriority,
            ),
        );
    }, [editor, updateToolbar]);

    const Divider: React.FC = () => {
        return <div className="w-1 bg-gray-300 mx-4" />;
    };

    return (
        <div
            className={`flex mb-1 p-4 items-center bg-transparent grid grid-cols-12 md:grid-cols-8 gap-2`}
            ref={toolbarRef}
        >
            <ToolbarButton
                onClick={() => editor.dispatchCommand(REDO_COMMAND, undefined)}
                isDisabled={!canRedo}
                label="Redo"
                iconName={faRotateRight}
            />
            <ToolbarButton
                onClick={() => editor.dispatchCommand(UNDO_COMMAND, undefined)}
                isDisabled={!canUndo}
                label="Undo"
                iconName={faRotateLeft}
            />
            <Divider />
            <ToolbarButton
                onClick={() =>
                    editor.dispatchCommand(FORMAT_TEXT_COMMAND, 'bold')
                }
                isDisabled={false}
                isActive={isBold}
                label="Bold"
                iconName={faBold}
            />
            <ToolbarButton
                onClick={() =>
                    editor.dispatchCommand(FORMAT_TEXT_COMMAND, 'italic')
                }
                isDisabled={false}
                isActive={isItalic}
                label="Italic"
                iconName={faItalic}
            />
            <ToolbarButton
                onClick={() =>
                    editor.dispatchCommand(FORMAT_TEXT_COMMAND, 'underline')
                }
                isDisabled={false}
                isActive={isUnderline}
                label="Underline"
                iconName={faUnderline}
            />
            <ToolbarButton
                onClick={() =>
                    editor.dispatchCommand(FORMAT_TEXT_COMMAND, 'strikethrough')
                }
                isDisabled={false}
                isActive={isStrikethrough}
                label="Strikethrough"
                iconName={faStrikethrough}
            />
            <Divider />
            <ToolbarButton
                onClick={() =>
                    editor.dispatchCommand(FORMAT_ELEMENT_COMMAND, 'left')
                }
                label="Left Align"
                isDisabled={false}
                iconName={faAlignLeft}
            />
            <ToolbarButton
                onClick={() =>
                    editor.dispatchCommand(FORMAT_ELEMENT_COMMAND, 'center')
                }
                label="Center Align"
                isDisabled={false}
                iconName={faAlignCenter}
            />
            <ToolbarButton
                onClick={() =>
                    editor.dispatchCommand(FORMAT_ELEMENT_COMMAND, 'right')
                }
                label="Right Align"
                isDisabled={false}
                iconName={faAlignRight}
            />
            {/*<ToolbarButton
                //Figure out lists
                onClick={() =>
                    editor.dispatchCommand(
                        INSERT_UNORDERED_LIST_COMMAND,
                        undefined,
                    )
                }
                label="BulletList"
                isDisabled={false}
                iconName={faListDots}
            /><Divider />*/}

            <ColorPicker color={fontColor} onChange={onFontColorSelect} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default ToolbarPlugin;

Theme
export const theme = () => {
    return {
        code: 'bg-gray-200 font-mono block px-8 py-8 pt-0.5 text-sm md:text-base',
        heading: {
            h1: 'text-2xl font-semibold mt-0 mb-1',
            h2: 'text-lg font-semibold mt-1 uppercase',
            h3: 'font-semibold mt-0 mb-1',
            h4: 'font-semibold mt-0 mb-1',
            h5: 'font-semibold mt-0 mb-1',
        },
        image: 'editor-image',
        link: 'text-blue-500 underline text-bold',
        list: {
            nested: {
                listitem: 'ml-4', // Indent nested list items by 1rem
                ol: 'list-decimal pl-8',
                ul: 'list-disc pl-8',
            },
            ol: 'list-decimal pl-8', // Use decimal numbers for ordered lists and add left padding of 2rem
            ul: 'list-disc pl-8', // Use disc bullets for unordered lists and add left padding of 2rem
            listitem: 'mb-2', // Add bottom margin of 0.5rem to list items
            listitemChecked: 'line-through text-gray-500', // Style checked list items with line-through and gray text
            listitemUnchecked: '', // Unchecked list items don't require additional styling
        },
        ltr: 'text-left',
        paragraph: 'mt-0 mb-2',
        quote: 'ml-4 italic border-l-4 border-gray-300 pl-4 py-2',
        rtl: 'text-right',
        text: {
            bold: 'font-bold',
            code: 'bg-gray-300 px-1 font-mono text-sm',
            hashtag: 'text-blue-600',
            italic: 'italic',
            overflowed: 'editor-text-overflowed',
            strikethrough: 'line-through',
            underline: 'underline',
            underlineStrikethrough: 'underline line-through',
        }
    };
};

RichText.tsx
import { useContext, useMemo, PropsWithChildren, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { AutoFocusPlugin } from '@lexical/react/LexicalAutoFocusPlugin';
import { LexicalComposer } from '@lexical/react/LexicalComposer';
import { ContentEditable } from '@lexical/react/LexicalContentEditable';
import LexicalErrorBoundary from '@lexical/react/LexicalErrorBoundary';
import { HistoryPlugin } from '@lexical/react/LexicalHistoryPlugin';
import { RichTextPlugin } from '@lexical/react/LexicalRichTextPlugin';
import ToolbarPlugin from './Toolbar/ToolbarPlugin';
import { ThemeContext, ThemeContextType } from '@contexts';
import { AutoLinkNode } from '@lexical/link';
import { AutoLinkPlugin } from '@lexical/react/LexicalAutoLinkPlugin';
import { MATCHERS, theme } from './Helpers';
import { LexicalEditor } from 'lexical';
import { EditorRefPlugin } from '@lexical/react/LexicalEditorRefPlugin';
import InitPlugin from './InitPlugin';
import EditablePlugin from './EditablePlugin';
import { ListNode, ListItemNode } from '@lexical/list';
import { ListPlugin } from '@lexical/react/LexicalListPlugin';

interface RichTextProps {
    editorRef: React.MutableRefObject<LexicalEditor | undefined>;
    editable: boolean;
    initStringId: number;
}

const RichText: React.FC<PropsWithChildren<RichTextProps>> = ({
    editorRef,
    editable,
    initStringId,
}: RichTextProps) => {
    const { isDarkMode } = useContext(ThemeContext) as ThemeContextType;
    const [initialized, setInitialized] = useState<boolean>(true);

    const secondaryBackground = useMemo(
        () => (isDarkMode ? 'bg-neutral-800' : 'bg-neutral-300'),
        [isDarkMode],
    );
    const textColor = useMemo(
        () => (isDarkMode ? 'text-neutral-200' : 'text-neutral-800'),
        [isDarkMode],
    );

    const Editor: React.FC = () => {
        const Placeholder: React.FC = () => {
            return (
                <div className="editor-placeholder">
                    Enter some rich text...
                </div>
            );
        };

        const editorConfig = {
            namespace: 'Phormulary',
            nodes: [AutoLinkNode, ListNode, ListItemNode],
            theme,
            onError(error: Error) {
                () => console.error(error);
            },
            editable: false,
        };

        return (
            <LexicalComposer initialConfig={editorConfig}>
                <div
                    className={`flex flex-col justify-center items-center font-normal text-left ${textColor}`}
                >
                    {editable && <ToolbarPlugin />}
                    <div
                        className={`min-h-150 mt-2 w-full text-sm outline-none px-10 py-15 caret-black rounded-md border-2 border-solid ${secondaryBackground}`}
                    >
                        <RichTextPlugin
                            contentEditable={
                                <ContentEditable
                                    className={`min-h-150 outline-none pt-2 bg-transparent`}
                                />
                            }
                            ErrorBoundary={LexicalErrorBoundary}
                            placeholder={<Placeholder />}
                        />
                        <EditorRefPlugin editorRef={editorRef} />
                        <AutoLinkPlugin matchers={MATCHERS} />
                        <HistoryPlugin />
                        <AutoFocusPlugin />
                        <ListPlugin />
                        <InitPlugin InitStringId={initStringId} />
                        <EditablePlugin editable={editable} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </LexicalComposer>
        );
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (initialized)
            setInitialized(false);
    }, [initialized]);

    return (
        <div className={`w-full rounded-md bg-transparent`}>
            <Editor />
        </div>
    );
};

export default RichText;

I tried looking up an answer. I have looked at the playground and tried to mimic code. I have looked at the basic react example and have followed that too.

I spent some time working on this today and found that the import for the css file is not getting loaded into the component. My workaround has been to put the App.css file in a public folder or CDN and use it from there and it worked like a charm. There is an ongoing bug report at github on this issue.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
